# Is QML Text.RichText URL caching possible?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

Say I have a [QML Text](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html) like:

```
Text {
 textFormat: Text.RichText
 text: '<img src="http://www.example.com/logo.jpg"/>'
}
```

Is there a built in  way to honor cache TTLs for the image source filed linked from the html snippet?  I realize I could swap

```
http://www.example.com/logo.jpg
```

for

```
file://path/to/app/logo.jpg
```

but then I will have to manage a file cache.  Is there a setting to have QT/QML do this for me automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be doable with help of `QQmlNetworkAccessManagerFactory`, `QNetworkAccessManager`, and `QNetworkDiskCache`:

```
class MyNetworkAccessManager : public QNetworkAccessManager
{
public:
    MyNetworkAccessManager(QObject *parent) : QNetworkAccessManager(parent) { }

protected:
    QNetworkReply *createRequest(Operation operation, const QNetworkRequest &request, QIODevice *outgoingData = nullptr) override
    {
        QNetworkRequest cacheRequest(request);
        cacheRequest.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest::CacheLoadControlAttribute, 
          (networkAccessible() == QNetworkAccessManager::Accessible) ? QNetworkRequest::PreferCache : QNetworkRequest::AlwaysCache);
        return QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest(operation, cacheRequest, outgoingData);
    }
};

class MyNetworkAccessManagerFactory : public QQmlNetworkAccessManagerFactory
{
public:
    QNetworkAccessManager *create(QObject *parent) override
    {
        QNetworkAccessManager *nam = new MyNetworkAccessManager(parent);
        QNetworkDiskCache *cache = new QNetworkDiskCache(nam);
        cache->setCacheDirectory(QDesktopServices::storageLocation(QDesktopServices::CacheLocation));
        nam->setCache(cache);
        return nam;
    }
};
```

And then install the factory on the engine:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.setNetworkAccessManagerFactory(new MyNetworkAccessManagerFactory);
engine.load(...);
```

Comment: I set a super-long cache time on header details from the webserver and I see it in the binary cache file with a long TTL, but if I turn off access to the internet, I get: "QML QQuickText: Network access is disabled." Is there a way to get it to check the cache and try to service the request before checking the internet connection?

Comment: Ok, I figured this out by manipulating `PreferCache` vs `AlwaysCache`.  I'm editing inline.